# Como fixar o tamanho de um botão no android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como evitar o problema a seguir?

Tenho esses botões e eu gostaria de deixá-los em um tamanho fixo, para que eles não ditorçam quando o celular for rotacionado.

[image: Tamanho Correto]

[image: Imagem errada.]

Estou usando RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >
```

Configurações do botões:

```
<Button
    android:text="Onde ir?"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:background="@drawable/mapabutton"
    android:textColor="@color/TextoBotao"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    tools:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só modificar o "wrap_content" para o tamanho desejado ou remover o layout_weight

```
<Button
    android:text="Onde ir?"
    // altere para o tamanho que você quizer
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:background="@drawable/mapabutton"
    android:textColor="@color/TextoBotao"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" //comentar essa linha também deve resolver
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    tools:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```